# Do adults speak this way "I want to allow all refugees"?

Tags: word-usage

Some English-learning tutorial gives a sentence

> ... I want to allow all refugees

[image]

Does it sounds like children's talking, e.g. "I want this", "I want that".

Do adults say things that way in real life, especially in formal discussion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like what it is.  An example of simplified English for learners.

It is both simpler and clearer than what a person would say if they were speaking.

"real" spoken English looks more like this:

> well I'm um in favour of it er immigration that is er I think think we should I mean not everybody of course but I don't mean criminals and er you know I guess there has to be some rules, but refugees, yeah I mean if you need asylum that means you you are in serious er danger or er er and er yeah we should offer these people er protection and er well protection from serious harm at least.

Real written English looks like

> This report has briefly analysed the current status of asylum in the UK today. Current debates on asylum are marred by a xenophobic anxiety about asylum that distorts the information we have available, and masks the legal obligations that the UK has.

Your example doesn't look particularly childish. It just looks like simplified speech for learners.

Comment: They tuk our JERBS!